# How to obtain static IP?

Tags: ip, static-ip, dynamic-ip

My service provider doesn't provide me static IP unless I pay them. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

No, pay them. Nothing is free.

Comment: Says the guy giving free advice on ServerFault. :-p +1 though.

Comment: It's ad supported, so technically. Hehe